# Div appear on mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a simple list. I'd like to make the div `img` appear when one of the `li` is hovered. I would like to make that `img` div appear at the current mouse coordinates.

I can make it all work, but not at the coordinates:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/fwgRE/2/

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul> 
<div class="img"> </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul {       
    font-size: 24pt;
}   
.img {
    display:none;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color:salmon;
    position: absolute;;
}
```

**jQ**:

```
$('li').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.img').fadeIn();
});  
$('li').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.img').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: clarify "at the coordinates" relative, at the top, bottom, under, above etc.

Answer (score 5):

change your js code to:

```
$('li').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('.img').css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY}).fadeIn();
});
```

will do the work

Answer (score 0):

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXDtK/)

```
$('li').mousemove(function( e ){
    $('.img').css({left: e.pageX+12, top: e.pageY-12}); // + correct position
}).hover(function( e ){
    $('.img').stop().fadeTo( 300, e.type=='mouseenter'? 1 : 0 );    
});
```

If you want to learn visually about mouse coordinates I created a demo:  http://jsbin.com/avupid/3

Comment: Your `$('html, body').scrollTop()` doesn't work for me in the jsbin demo. Works if I change it to `$(document).scrollTop()` or `$(window).scrollTop()`

Comment: @funkwurm works for me both FF and Chrome. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm on a Chromium based browser under Mac OS X and the scrollTop() value stays 0 even if I scroll down and then move the mouse. I do still see the other number update so the script is doing something, but evidently the value scrollTop() returns just stays 0 no matter what.

Comment: @funkwurm thanks so much for this valuable information. I'll take an extensive look ASAP (I'm on Win currently)